# Blender TCP connection with another application

Tags: python, external-applications

I'm completely inexperienced in this topic, however I've done a lot of research on setting up a server in Blender for TCP communication with another application. It seems most examples I've found follow the [Blender Cloud Add-on's implementation](https://github.com/timkruse/blender-tcpserver/blob/main/async_loop.py) of `asyncio`.

In [this repository's TCP implementation](https://github.com/timkruse/blender-tcpserver/blob/main/tcp_server.py#L73), an `asyncio.Protocol` instance puts the received data into a `asyncio.Queue()`.

I have two questions:

1. How can I trigger an event when data is received that a Blender Operator can listen for?
2. How can I send messages to the client when something updates in my Blender scene (e.g. selecting an object)?**

** With regards to sending a message, I've seen [the TCP Echo Server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server), which seems to have an example that uses `self.transport.write(data)` to send the data back to the client, however this does not work with the below code.

SERVER

```py
from asyncio.queues import QueueEmpty
from os import name
import bpy
import asyncio
from typing import Optional
from struct import unpack
from . import async_loop
import re

tcpserver = None
coroutine = None

class TCPProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    addr : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="addr", description="TCP Server Address", default="127.0.0.1")
    port : bpy.props.IntProperty(name="port", description="TCP Server Port", default=55555, min=1000, max=2**16-1)


class TCPServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.transports.BaseTransport) -> None:
        self.transport = transport
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print(f"connection from {peername}")
        self.counter = 0
        
    def connection_lost(self, exc: Optional[Exception]) -> None:
        self.transport = None
        print("connection lost")

    def data_received(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        dataQueue = bpy.types.Scene.tcpDataQueue
        print("data_received")
        self.transport.write(data)
        dataQueue.put_nowait(data)


class VIEW3D_PT_tcpserver(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TCP Server"
    bl_label = "TCP Server"

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row(align=True)
        props = row.operator("tcpserver.start", text="Start")
        props.server_addr = bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties.addr
        props.server_port = bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties.port
        row.operator("tcpserver.stop", text="Stop")
        self.layout.label(text="Running" if tcpserver else "Stopped")

        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties, "addr", text="Address")
        col.prop(bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties, "port", text="Port")

class TCPSERVER_OT_tcpserver_start(async_loop.AsyncModalOperatorMixin, bpy.types.Operator):
    """Start a TCP Server in the background"""
    bl_idname = "tcpserver.start"
    bl_label = "Start a TCP Server in the background"

    server_addr : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="addr", description="TCP Server Address", default="127.0.0.1")
    server_port : bpy.props.IntProperty(name="port", description="TCP Server Port", default=55555, min=1000, max=2**16-1)

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context,None)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        global tcpserver
        global coroutine
        if tcpserver is None:
            if re.search("^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$", self.server_addr):
                bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties.addr = self.server_addr
                bpy.context.scene.TCPProperties.port = self.server_port
                bpy.types.Scene.tcpDataQueue = asyncio.Queue()
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                coroutine = loop.create_server(TCPServer, self.server_addr, self.server_port)
                tcpserver = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
                print(f"TCP server started {self.server_addr}:{self.server_port}")
                return async_loop.AsyncModalOperatorMixin.invoke(self, context, event)
            else:
                print("Invalid IP address")
                return {"CANCELLED"}
        else:
            print("Server already started.")
            return {"CANCELLED"}

class TCPSERVER_OT_tcpserver_stop(async_loop.AsyncModalOperatorMixin, bpy.types.Operator):
    """Stops the TCP Server"""
    bl_idname = "tcpserver.stop"
    bl_label = "Stops the TCP Server"

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        global tcpserver
        global coroutine
        if tcpserver is not None:
            tcpserver.close()
            tcpserver = None
            coroutine = None
            print("TCP Server stopped")
        else:
            print("Failed to stop TCP Server")
        
        return {"FINISHED"}

classes = (
    TCPProperties,
    TCPSERVER_OT_tcpserver_start, 
    TCPSERVER_OT_tcpserver_stop,
    VIEW3D_PT_tcpserver
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.TCPProperties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=TCPProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
    del(bpy.types.Scene.TCPProperties)
```

CLIENT

```py
import asyncio


class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = 'Hello World!'

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        '127.0.0.1', 55555)

    # Wait until the protocol signals that the connection
    # is lost and close the transport.
    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Your server class contains the line `from . import async_loop` but you haven't included async_loop.  Can you paste it into the question?  I'd like to test any answers I manage to produce.

Comment: There's an answer to your first question in add-on you mentioned: [this class](https://github.com/timkruse/blender-tcpserver/blob/main/async_loop.py#L132) implements a Modal Operator that does something similar to what you want.

Comment: The answer to your second question is that there's no clean way, but that the usual approach is to add a [depsgraph_update_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) application handler.  In the handler, check to see if the update is one you want to send and send the message with async i/o.

Comment: and finally, StackExchange does not like 2 questions in one post.  Recommend you edit this question and delete the 2nd question and post a new question with the 2nd.  It's OK for the 2nd to refer to this one for details so you don't have to duplicate information.

Comment: @MartyFouts the `async_loop` is included in two places: the "Blender Cloud add-on" link and the "this repository's TCP implementation"
https://github.com/timkruse/blender-tcpserver

Comment: Got it. thatnks.

Comment: is it possible to use transport.write(self.message.encode()) to send the messages to the client? @Dr.Pontchartrain